# Sums of form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\pm1)^n}{n^{5/2}} \cos(nx)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Can we do the sums

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\pm1)^n}{n^{5/2}} \sin(nx)\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\pm1)^n}{n^{5/2}} \cos(nx) 
\end{align}

They appear similar to known results e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321736/the-fourier-series-sum-n-1-infty-1-n-cos-nx), [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210644/proving-sum-n-1-infty-frac-cosnn4-frac-pi-490-frac-pi-2?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552640/series-sum-n-1-infty-frac-cosnxn2), but I can't solve it myself or find an answer.

From a numerical investigation, I find e.g.,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{5/2}} \cos(nx) \approx - 3/4 \pi |\sin(x/2)| + \pi/2
$$

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{5/2}} \cos(nx) \approx - 3/4 \pi |\cos(x/2)| + \pi/2
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\pm1)^n}{n^{5/2}} \sin(nx) \approx \pm \sin(x)
$$
Are these results exact? If not, what are the answers? and why are these approximations rather good?

Comment: Most of such known cases reduce to the Fourier series of the (periodic) Bernoulli polynomials. For these case, we are out of luck and I suspect they may not have a closed form.

Comment: I'm checking my guesses to high order in Mathematica... they don't appear to be exact.

Answer (score 1):

*Only a hint:*

Using the considerations in [The sum of fractional powers $\sum\limits_{k=1}^x k^t$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912173/the-sum-of-fractional-powers-sum-limits-k-1x-kt) I only found

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^{5/2}}(\sin(xk)+\cos(xk))=-\frac{(2\pi)^2}{3}\zeta(-\frac{3}{2},\frac{x}{2\pi})$$

and therefore

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^{5/2}}\cos(xk)=-\frac{(2\pi)^2}{6}\left(\zeta(-\frac{3}{2},\frac{x}{2\pi})+\zeta(-\frac{3}{2},-\frac{x}{2\pi})\right)$$

and

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^{5/2}}\sin(xk)=-\frac{(2\pi)^2}{6}\left(\zeta(-\frac{3}{2},\frac{x}{2\pi})-\zeta(-\frac{3}{2},-\frac{x}{2\pi})\right)$$

so that one can compare $\enspace\displaystyle -\frac{(2\pi)^2}{6}\zeta(-\frac{3}{2},\frac{\pm x}{2\pi})\enspace$ with the assumptions for

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(xk)}{k^{5/2}}\enspace$ and $\enspace\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(xk)}{k^{5/2}}$ .

To calculate the Hurwitz Zetafunction $\,\zeta(s,x)\,$ especially for negative $\,s\,$ see

the different possibilities here: $\enspace$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function

Comment: Thanks, isn't this a solution for 2 of the sums since I can identify even/odd parts of zeta with cos/sin sums

Comment: @innisfree : If $\,\displaystyle -\frac{(2\pi)^2}{3}\zeta(-\frac{3}{2},\frac{x}{2\pi})\neq \sin(x)-\frac{3\pi}{4}|\sin\frac{x}{2}|+\frac{\pi}{2}\,$ (a test with one valid value $x$ is enough) then at least you know that your assumptions can not be an exact result. But it doesn’t mean here, that all are wrong, only that at least one is wrong.

Comment: Yes. But I can test each one individually by identifying even/odd parts.

Comment: I know what you mean but first I was not sure if is possible to substitute $x$ by $-x$ . But now: it works because of $|x|<2\pi$ .

Comment: The wiki link is helpful. Your answer looks like a s=5/2 case of Hurwitz's formula

Comment: Not only "looks like", indeed it is. :-) This makes it possible to discuss such series by using the characteristics of the Hurwitz zeta function. --- You can also check characteristics of polylogarithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm .