# Evaluation of :$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n \log n}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, polylogarithm, transcendental-functions

I have tried to evaluate this sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n \log n}{n}$ using :$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n }{n}$ , Really the partial sum of the titled series given by polylogarithm function and lerch transcendent functions as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(+logn+sin(n)%2Fn)),+n%3D1+to+infty), But i'm not familiar about convergence of these function for large n , Then my question here is :

What is the exact value of :$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n \log n}{n}$$ ?

Comment: Honestly I would not expect a closed form to exist.

Comment: @gammatester But Wolfy says it is around 0.007.

Comment: @szeto: Yes, it seems to be non-zero, and therefore I deleted my comment. I have plotted with Maple because here WA does give a result. Plotting up to 2000 shows that it is slightly above 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$0<x<1$ : $\enspace\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n}{n}\sin(2\pi n x) = \frac{\pi}{2}\left(\ln\frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(1-x)}-(1-2x)(\gamma + \ln(2\pi))\right)$

see e.g. [E. E. Kummer, page 1 to 4](http://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/en/fs1/object/display/bsb10525489_00011.html?zoom=1.0)

See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912173/the-sum-of-fractional-powers-sum-limits-k-1x-kt) , look for the first derivation for $t$ of $B_t(x)$ , a generalization of the Bernoulli polynomial and it’s Fourier series.

*It follows:*

> $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin n\ln n}{n} = \frac{\pi}{2}\left(\ln\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)}{\Gamma\left(1-\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)}-\left(1-\frac{1}{\pi}\right)(\gamma + \ln(2\pi))\right)$$

Comment: nice closed form

Comment: @zeraouliarafik : It has to do with the Fourier series for the logarithm of the Gamma function. :)

Comment: You mean something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Fourier_series_expansion

Comment: This is amazing.

Comment: @gammatester : Of course, but I haven't checked Wikipedia or others. It's good that you've mentioned it.